# Getting PHP processing to happen in the background

Tags: php, include, cron, exec, background-process

I am working on a PHP website, and I am moving it over to a new server. The new server I am moving to does not have CRON compatibility. To compensate for this I have devised a system using time formats and database tables and more to run my code instead.

What I am having a problem with is this bit of code:

```
if ($lasttime < $pretime)
{
    $newtime = strtotime("now");

    queryMysql("UPDATE time SET time=".$newtime." WHERE time=".$lasttime);

    include_once 'grabber/grabber.php';
}
```

Specifically it's the `include_once 'grabber/grabber.php';` which is causing the problem. When the timer comes round and this code runs, it gets to the include and then the code stops, with no error provided, so the include fails. I have tried changing it to an `exec()` but to be honest I don't completely understand how `exec()` works and if it is the correct thing to do. This is how I used it:

```
if ($lasttime < $pretime)
{
    $newtime = strtotime("now");

    queryMysql("UPDATE time SET time=".$newtime." WHERE time=".$lasttime);

    $grabber = $base."grabber/grabber.php";    

    exec($grabber);
}
```

This does not stop the code and seems to run but it doesn't actually work, if `grabber/grabber.php` runs correctly then I get an email to confirm using the PHP `mail()` function

If anyone could help me solve this or shed some light that would be brilliant.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try the full version of exec? `exec ($grabber,$output,$return_code)` and see what $output returns?

Comment: @charlesbridge would using `exec` mean that the code would run without causing slow loading times? also in this case of using the 'full version' what would i put into `$output` and `$return_code`?

Comment: You should see the manual page ( http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php ), $output and $return_code are empty vars that get filled in by exec upon completion.  There's also some example code there that may help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably an issue with the file location or permissions. There should be some kind of error, or the code doesn't stop, but you don't properly check that or there is some kind of an issue with the code in `grabber.php` itself. Add some debugging lines - print the filename, so you can check for errors in the path/name; add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` somewhere above the `include_once` line; make sure the file is where you're trying to open it from, taking into account relative paths, etc. Make sure you have permissions to run this file.

exec() is not what you need in this case, at least not in the way that you're trying to use it.

If that doesn't help - give some more information about how you run the scripts that you've shown, what's in the `grabber.php` file, what errors you get, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, Adding the error_reporting to it has shown me that I had a duplicate function which was stopping the page to run when included into the main website. I have fixed this and it all runs correctly now. Thanks agian

Comment: You're welcome. Remember, putting `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` or something similar, is pretty much the first thing you need to do in situations like this. It's a good idea to actually have this settings all the time while you're developing, so if an error occurs you can see what it is right away.

Comment: yeah, its just this new server is quite different, its a cloud service so does do error reporting and more like other standard servers.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming your server is *nix) If you want to use `exec()` you need to place a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of the script that points to the PHP executable and give it execute permissions.

Or (this is probably the better/more portable approach), change

```
$grabber = $base."grabber/grabber.php";    
exec($grabber);
```

to

```
$grabber = "php ".$base."grabber/grabber.php";    
exec($grabber);
```

...as if you were running it from a terminal.

However, I doubt this will solve the problem - I think the answer is more likely to be one of these things:

- A parse error in `grabber.php`. Keep in mind that there are slight syntax differences between major PHP versions - if your PHP version is different on your old/new hosts, this may be the problem.
- A call to a function that was defined on your old host but not on your new host, because of a difference in PHP version or installed extensions
- `grabber.php` was corrupted during the move between servers

Try it with the `include_once`, but do `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);` to make sure you actually see any errors. How are you calling you main script? How will you see the errors? Edit the question with this info, any code from `grabber.php` you think may be relevant and I will expand this answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will give you suggestion a try. I know that `grabber.php` is no faulty as if I type in the full url into my browser it runs correctly, the DB updates and I get my confirmation email, so the problem is solely with the `include` or `exec`.